# Extend customer information

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am working on Sitecore Commerce 9 and using Sitecore commerce customer for storing customer information.

While customer registration, I would like to save few more information about the customer. Can somebody help in extending Sitecore Commerce Customer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After a few days of research, I found one easy way to extend Sitecore 9 Commerce Customer.

We can use xConnect Custom Facets to store custom Customer information. Below link is helpful in creating xConnect Custom Facets:

https://jitendrasitecore.wordpress.com/2018/02/12/xconnect-create-custom-facet/

Hoping it would be helpful for others :)

Comment: Can you add also some code snippet to the answer so it is much easier to determine how you have extended Commerce Customer? Are you also exposing this new facet in Customers in Commerce Business Tools? If yes would be great to see code snippet also for that to have the full picture. Thanks